# Error while binding through ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I am doing ajax call in Asp.Net MVC with this code

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetAllFacts", "Home")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            //$('#AllFacts_Data').append("<div class='col-md-4'><div class='text-center facts-data-box bg_facts_grey'><div class='inner-div'><span><img src=" + data[0].ImageUrl + " class='image_top '></span><div class='text-center twit-all-content facts-content_blu'>'" + data[0].Content + "'</div></div></div></div>");
            //$('#AllFacts_Data').append("<div class='col-md-4'><div class='text-center facts-data-box bg_facts_grey'><div class='inner-div'><span><img src=" + data[1].ImageUrl + " class='image_top '></span><div class='text-center twit-all-content facts-content_blu'>'" + data[1].Content + "'</div></div></div></div>");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
```

This hits to my Get Method GetAllFacts() with following codes

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetAllFacts()
{
    try
    {
        using (var context = new DbDemo())
        {
            var allData_Facts = context.Objblog.Take(2).ToList();
            return Json(allData_Facts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
    return Json("false", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This is my code which returns list with 2 data properly, but after that it is not going to success method it alerts error as per Ajax error function.

Where I am wrong?

Comment: Use your browser tools to inspect the response (Network tab) to see whatthe error is

Comment: in console HTML Shows `System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have checked my `System.Web.Mvc` version in reference and also in `Web.config` it is 5.0.0.0

Comment: Go through your `web.config` file and check all the version numbers (probably an issue with a binding redirect) but not sure how you even got the page to load if your getting that error.

Comment: I matched all the reference version to my Web.Config's `newVersion` all are matched. Ans this line `return Json(allData_Facts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` returns 2 data properly as per my requirements.

Comment: If your going to the error function then its not returning the data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try by

- Remove assembly reference System.Web.Mvc out of your project.
- Use nuget to install System.Web.Mvc for you project.
- Verify Web.config to make sure it have System.Web.Mvc assembly.
- Run to check.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Home/GetAllFacts',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
               // connect to server successful and everything's ok
               // access to server returned data: data.alldata
            } else {
               // connect to server successful but something went wrong
               alert(data.ex); // throw exception message
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            // connect to server failure
        }
    });
```

controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetAllFacts()
{
    try
    {
        using (var context = new DbDemo())
        {
            var allData_Facts = context.Objblog.Take(2).ToList();
            return Json(new { success = true, alldata = allData_Facts }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, ex = e.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
```